# How to find VLC Attribute Library (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vlc

I have this Delegates thats been wrote like this

```
public static T GetInteropDelegate<T>(IntPtr handler)
    {
        string functionName = null;
        var procAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
        var supportedPlatform = UMPSettings.SupportedPlatform;

        try
        {
            var attrs = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InteropFunctionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs.Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("Could not find the LibVLCAttribute.");

            var attr = (InteropFunctionAttribute)attrs[0];
            functionName = attr.FunctionName;
            if (_interopDelegates.ContainsKey(functionName))
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(_interopDelegates[attr.FunctionName], typeof(T), null);

            if (supportedPlatform == UMPSettings.Platforms.Win)
                procAddress = WindowsInterops.GetProcAddress(handler, attr.FunctionName);
            if (supportedPlatform == UMPSettings.Platforms.Mac)
                procAddress = MacInterops.dlsym(handler, attr.FunctionName);
            if (supportedPlatform == UMPSettings.Platforms.Linux)
                procAddress = LinuxInterops.dlsym(handler, attr.FunctionName);

            if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Win32Exception("Can't get process address from " + handler + " library: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var delegateForFunctionPointer = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(T));
            _interopDelegates[attr.FunctionName] = delegateForFunctionPointer;
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(delegateForFunctionPointer, typeof(T), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("GetMethod error: " + functionName);
            throw new MissingMethodException(string.Format("The address of the function '{0}' does not exist in " + handler + " library.", functionName), e);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem with this is that . It always throw the error

> Exception: Could not find the LibVLCAttribute.
>   UMP.InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate[libvlc_media_get_stats] (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/InteropLibraryLoader.cs:149)
>   Rethrow as MissingMethodException: The address of the function '' does not exist in 235143168 library.
>   UMP.InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate[libvlc_media_get_stats] (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/Scripts/Sources/InteropLibraryLoader.cs:173)
>   UMP.VlcMethods.LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary (IntPtr handler) (at Assets/UniversalMediaPlayer/StreamingWork/VlcMethods.cs:59)

Now there's a script that holds my method of vlc

**VlcMethod.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UMP.Wrappers;



namespace UMP
{
public class VlcMethods
{
    private static VlcMethods instance = null;
    public static VlcMethods Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new VlcMethods();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int libvlc_media_get_stats(IntPtr p_md, out libvlc_media_stats_t p_stats);
    public libvlc_media_get_stats Libvlc_media_get_stats;

    public VlcMethods()
    {
        var libraryExtension = string.Empty;
        var settings = UMPSettings.Instance;

        IntPtr handler = InteropLibraryLoader.Load(Wrapper.LibraryVLCName, settings.UseExternalLibs, settings.AdditionalLibsPath, libraryExtension);
        if (handler != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary(handler);
        }
    }

    ~VlcMethods()
    {
        instance = null;
    }

    private void LoadMethodsFromVLCLibrary(IntPtr handler)
    {
        if (handler == IntPtr.Zero)
            return;

        try
        {
            //Libvlc_media_get_stats = (libvlc_media_get_stats)InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate<libvlc_media_get_stats>(handler);
            //[Pk Recode 29/12 2017]
            Libvlc_media_get_stats = InteropLibraryLoader.GetInteropDelegate<libvlc_media_get_stats>(handler);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            InteropLibraryLoader.Unload(handler);
            throw new ArgumentException(
                String.Format("No suitable " + Wrapper.LIBRARY_VLC_NAME + " could be found in the provided path: {0}", exception.Message),
                Wrapper.LIBRARY_VLC_NAME + "Directory", exception);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now i'm using also my vlc method for checking the network condition which is like this

```
 libvlc_media_stats_t preStat;
    VlcMethods.Instance.Libvlc_media_get_stats(mediaObj, out preStat);

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        libvlc_media_stats_t t;
        VlcMethods.Instance.Libvlc_media_get_stats(mediaObj, out t);

        int playedBuff = t.i_demux_read_bytes - preStat.i_demux_read_bytes;            
        int downBuff = t.i_read_bytes - preStat.i_read_bytes;
        int storageBuff = t.i_read_bytes - t.i_demux_read_bytes;

        sumStorageBuffer -= storagebuffQueue.Dequeue();
        storagebuffQueue.Enqueue(storageBuff);
        sumStorageBuffer += storageBuff;

        sumDownBuff -= downBuffQueue.Dequeue();
        downBuffQueue.Enqueue(downBuff);
        sumDownBuff += downBuff;

        averageStorageBuffer = (sumStorageBuffer / (float)storagebuffQueue.Count) / playedBuff;
        averageDownloadBuffer = (sumDownBuff / (float)downBuffQueue.Count) / playedBuff;

        preStat = t;
```

And now i don't know really why it is throwing that error. -_-. Anyone can site ? Thank you in advance. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the idea that i need to delete my vlcmethod.cs and on my livecam.cs

```
private IEnumerator CheckNetworkCondition()
{
    averageStorageBuffer = 0;      
    averageDownloadBuffer = 0;     
    Queue<float> storagebuffQueue = new Queue<float>();
    float sumStorageBuffer = 0;

    Queue<float> downBuffQueue = new Queue<float>();
    float sumDownBuff = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < averageCount; i++)
    {
        storagebuffQueue.Enqueue(0);
        downBuffQueue.Enqueue(0);
    }

    MediaStats? preStat = null;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        var mediaStats = new MediaStats();

        if (ump.PlatformPlayer is MediaPlayerStandalone)
            mediaStats = (ump.PlatformPlayer as MediaPlayerStandalone).MediaStats;

        if (ump.PlatformPlayer is MediaPlayerAndroid)
            mediaStats = (ump.PlatformPlayer as MediaPlayerAndroid).MediaStats;

        if (preStat == null)
            preStat = mediaStats;

        int playedBuff = mediaStats.DemuxReadBytes - preStat.Value.DemuxReadBytes;            
        int downBuff = mediaStats.InputReadBytes - preStat.Value.InputReadBytes;
        int storageBuff = mediaStats.InputReadBytes - mediaStats.DemuxReadBytes;

        sumStorageBuffer -= storagebuffQueue.Dequeue();
        storagebuffQueue.Enqueue(storageBuff);
        sumStorageBuffer += storageBuff;

        sumDownBuff -= downBuffQueue.Dequeue();
        downBuffQueue.Enqueue(downBuff);
        sumDownBuff += downBuff;

        averageStorageBuffer = (sumStorageBuffer / (float)storagebuffQueue.Count) / playedBuff;
        averageDownloadBuffer = (sumDownBuff / (float)downBuffQueue.Count) / playedBuff;

        preStat = mediaStats;

        UpdatekNetworkCondition();
    }
}
```